# Redirect to a url based on user input to an autocomplete field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have found coding for both things i'm trying to do but have no idea how to combine them.  I have copied below the two blocks of code I've found that seem to work individually.  I don't know very much about javascript but trying to learn.. thanks

redirect to a url based on user input

```
<form id='formName' name='formName' onsubmit='redirect();return false;'>
        <input type='text' id='userInput' name='userInput' value=''>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    function redirect() {
       var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toLowerCase();
        switch(input) {
            case 'keyword1':
                window.location.replace('page1.html');
                break;
            case 'keyword2':
                window.location.replace('page2.html');
                break;
            default:
                window.location.replace('error.html');
                break;
        }


    }
    </script>
```

And the autocomplete

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

For an hardcoded autocomplete solution, that redirects when option is selected you could do something like this:

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
    //hardcodes autocomplete options
    var availableTags = [
      "www.google.com",
      "www.facebook.com",
    ];
   //initiate autocomplete on the #tages input using the tags defined above
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
 //Watch for a change to the #tags text box
 $(function(){
   $("#tags").change(function(){
           //When value changes, take that value and set variable
           var x = $(this).val();
          //Change window location using our variable
           window.location.replace(x);
    });
 });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

The autocompelte is pretty simple, follow the instructions on the jqui website you provided. Then you can simple add a event handler to the auto complete input, which , when changed, will open a page with it's current value.... This part of the code is:

```
 $(function(){
   $("#tags").change(function(){
           var x = $(this).val();
           window.location.replace(x);
    });
 });
```

Comment: this will work as long as the value entered is an actual web page. Autocomplete only gives you suggestions. It doesn't force you to select one of it's options. It would be better to use the 'redirect()' method as written. If you want to automatically trigger it using the change event of the textbox you could say: - $(function(){ $('#tags').on('change', redirect); });

Answer (score 0):

So do I add this to the head

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and this below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    // this creates an array of words to use in the autocomplete
    var availableTags = ["Keyword1", "Keyword2", "Keyword3" ];
    // this attaches the autocomplete function to your textbox and assigns the array of words as the source
    $( "#userInput" ).autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
});
```

to this:

```
<form id='formName' name='formName' onsubmit='redirect();return false;'>
    <input type='text' id='userInput' name='userInput' value=''>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function redirect() {
   var input = document.getElementById('userInput').value.toLowerCase();
    switch(input) {
        case 'keyword1':
            window.location.replace('page1.html');
            break;
        case 'keyword2':
            window.location.replace('page2.html');
            break;
        default:
            window.location.replace('error.html');
            break;
    }


}
</script>
```

Sorry just a bit confused? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

OK so first of all. The Autocomplete is a feature of jQuery-UI. jQuery-UI is a plugin for jQuery which is a javascript library. And IMHO the best one around. So if you want to add autocomplete to your form then you need to add references to both jQuery and jQuery-UI. You can download them and host them on your server locally or you can use a Content Delivery Network like google to reference them. You'll also need to reference a jQuery-UI CSS theme.

So put this in the head of your html:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

put this at the foot of your page just above the closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        // this creates an array of words to use in the autocomplete
        var availableTags = ["Keyword1", "Keyword2", "Keyword3" ];
        // this attaches the autocomplete function to your textbox and assigns the array of words as the source
        $( "#userInput" ).autocomplete({ source: availableTags });
    });
</script>
```

With this in the page with the rest of what you have above it should work.